# Max $P= 7x + 5y + 6z$ Subject to: $x + y − z ≤ 3 x + 2y + z ≤ 8 x + y ≤ 5 x ≥ 0, y ≥ 0, z ≥ 0$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

> Linear programming problem using the simplex method. Max $P= 7x + 5y + 6z$
>
> Subject to: $$x + y − z \le 3 x + 2y + z \le 8 x + y ≤ 5$$   $x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$

My try: I know how to solve by simplex method but here constraints are linked .So, plz just  give me a hint so that  could solve it.Thank you.

Comment: why don't you simplify $$x+y-z\le 3x+2y+z$$?

Comment: There is also another one i.e $8x+y$.

Answer (score 1):

You could add dummy variables $u$ and $v$:
\begin{cases}
x+y-z \le u\\
3x+2y+z \ge u \\
3x+2y+z \le v \\
8x+8y \ge v \\
8x+8y \le 5 
\end{cases}